# how to print shell command in an email through python

Tags: python, pandas, powershell

I am trying to print shell commands in the email body through python script.
I have a pandas dataframe which contains shell commands

```
df1=
Copy_Commands
0  cp /directory path1/*.PDF /destination directory & disown
1  cp /directory path2/*.PDF /destination directory & disown
```

I converted this df1 to html table

```
df1_html = df1.to_html(index=False, header=False)
```

Now if I print this `df1_html` on the console the output is exactly same as `df1` but in the mail it is printing every `.PDF` file name present in the directory `path1` and directory `path2["cp /directory path1/1.PDF /destination directory & disown cp /directory path1/2.PDF /destination directory & disown..."]` instead of `"cp /directory path1/*.PDF /destination directory & disown"`

Code:

```
   # mail_success_body_txt_file=path to mail_success_body.txt 

   with open(mail_success_body, 'r') as file:
       data = file.read().replace('df1_html', df1_html)

   os.system("""sh '%s' '%s' "%s" """ % (mail_success_body_txt_file, arg2, data))
```

mail_success_body.txt file content:

```
<html>
<body style='font-family:Arial; font-size:12px'>
    Hi, <br/>
    
    Copy Commands : <br/>
    df1_html
    <br/>
    
    

    Regards, <br/>
    XXXXX<br/>
    <br/>

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone suggest what's the issue with my code

Comment: shell automatiacally convert path with `*` to matching files. You may have to print path in `' '` (not `" "`) to keep it in shell

Comment: I don't know what you have in shell program but I would do all in Python. You could create body file with `{}` and later read file to python and use `.format()` to put `df` in place of `{}`.

Comment: I have given the path in single quotes only(' '). Still it does the same.

Comment: you have to use `' '` inside dataframe. But maybe you should also show shell script code. But frankly I would try to do all without shell script.

Comment: or maybe you shouldn't read data in python and send it as text but you should write data in file and shell script should read data from file on its own.

Comment: BTW: you put data in `" "`, not in `' '`, and for shell it makes difference. It may replace `*` even in `" "` (at least it replaces shell variables in `" "`) but it shouldn't replace in `' '`

Comment: As you suggested I used ' ' inside dataframe for every record. Though it is doing the same thing just that ' ' are added to it as well. I will try to write data in a file instead of reading...
Is there any way that * can be read as string rather than character so that it's constant and print only the shell command rather than going inside directory and printing all the files

Comment: I am not sure how should I send the email without using shell script

Comment: python has standard module [smtplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html) (Send Mail Trasfer Protocol) and also [imaplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html) (for protocol `IMAP` to read and send mails).

Comment: okay let me try

Comment: links [smtplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html), [imaplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html). There are some examples in documentation but you can also find many questions on Stackoveflow with example code, or tutorials on Internet.

Comment: python has also standard module [email](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html) to better format mail before sending it with `smtplib`